# Pyqt threaded processes application crashing on second launch

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5

I made a small test application to practice threading - on the first launch it works fine, with the loop printing to the console while the gui is still running. However, the kernel crashes and restarts if I close the app and then open it again afterwards.

I've had this issue before with pyqt5 applications, and it's usually solved when I add the QCoreApplication.instance() section at the end of my script. I was wondering whether this time there was an error with the way I implemented my threading.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.working = True

    def work(self):
        while self.working:
            # do stuff here
            print("I'm running")
            time.sleep(1)

        self.finished.emit() # alert our gui that the loop stopped

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Program")

        self.startbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.startbtn.resize(self.startbtn.minimumSizeHint())
        self.startbtn.move(50, 50)
        self.stopbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.stopbtn.move(50, 100)
        self.stopbtn.resize(self.stopbtn.minimumSizeHint())

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.startbtn.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)  # start the thread when we click the start button
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.work)  # begin our worker object's loop
        self.stopbtn.clicked.connect(self.stop_loop)  # stop the loop on the stop button click
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.loop_finished)  # do something in the gui when the worker loop ends

    def stop_loop(self):
        self.worker.working = False

    def loop_finished(self):
        print('Looped Finished')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication.instance()               # Fixes error with kernel crashing on second run of application
    if app is None:                                 # PyQt doesn't like multiple QApplications in the same process, therefore
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)                # apart from the initial run, the first QApplication instance will run
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```